# How to Write an Expresso Test for Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-intent, junit, android-recyclerview, android-espresso

I have a full working project but would like to write an espresso test for the main activity which basically test for counting recyclerview items, the code consume JSON values and pass a list to an adapter with the help of recycler view to display. I had a test written but i kept on getting null objects as response and it fails below are the codes

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  RecipeTestDownloader.DelayerCallback  {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
ProgressDialog pd;
List<Recipe> recipes;
private static Context mContext;

@Nullable
private SimpleIdlingResource mIdlingResource;


@VisibleForTesting
@NonNull
public IdlingResource getIdlingResource() {
    if (mIdlingResource == null) {
        mIdlingResource = new SimpleIdlingResource();
    }
    return mIdlingResource;
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe_list);

    initViews();
    mContext = this;
    RecipeSyncUtils.initialize(this);
    getIdlingResource();
}

public Activity getActivity(){
    Context context = this;
    while (context instanceof ContextWrapper){
        if (context instanceof Activity){
            return (Activity) context;
        }
        context = ((ContextWrapper) context).getBaseContext();
    }
    return null;

}

private void initViews(){

    boolean isPhone = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.is_phone);

    if (isPhone) {

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    } else {

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        if (getActivity().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
        } else {
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));
        }

    }

    RecipeSyncUtils.initialize(this);
    loadJSON();

}

private void loadJSON(){

    Service serviceAPI = Client.getClient();
    Call<JsonArray> loadRecipeCall = serviceAPI.readRecipeArray();

    loadRecipeCall.enqueue(new Callback<JsonArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonArray> call, Response<JsonArray> response) {

            try {

                String recipeString = response.body().toString();

                Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Recipe>>() {}.getType();
                recipes = JsonUtils.getRecipeListFromJson(recipeString, listType);

                recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecipeAdapter(getApplicationContext(), recipes));
                recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);



            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("onResponse", "There is an error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonArray> call, Throwable t) {

            Log.d("onFailure", t.toString());

        }


    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    RecipeTestDownloader.downloadRecipe(this, MainActivity.this, mIdlingResource);
}




@Override
public void onDone(ArrayList<Recipe> recipes) {

}
}
```

RecipeAdapter.class

```
public class RecipeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecipeAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<Recipe> recipeList;


public RecipeAdapter(Context mContext, List<Recipe> objects){
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.recipeList = objects;
}

@Override
public RecipeAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i){
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.recipe_card, viewGroup, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecipeAdapter.MyViewHolder viewHolder, int i){


    viewHolder.title.setText(recipeList.get(i).getName());
    String thumbnail = recipeList.get(i).getImage();

    Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(thumbnail)
            .into(viewHolder.image);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount(){
    return recipeList.size();

}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView title;
    ImageView image;

    public MyViewHolder(View view){

        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
        image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.recipeImage);

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                if (pos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                    Recipe clickedDataItem = recipeList.get(pos);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, RecipeDetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Recipe", clickedDataItem);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "You clicked " + clickedDataItem.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

I need help on how to write the espresso test on this MainActivty i.e getItemCount test, text matcher or any test implementation